# How to make the texts in latex poster more compact

Tags: enumerate, baposter

I am making a poster with **latex baposter** (maybe I really should have used ppt instead.) I wonder how do I make the text more compact under latex enumerate mode.

The following figure shows my problem. I would like to move the words in the black circle into the spaces beblow the second point. Now these one and a half word stick out above the third point. 
[image]
below are the code

```
\headerbox{Contribution}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=2,row=0,above=contact,below=results}{%

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item{
    Not all matters are deliberated by the full board. Some are delegated to
subcommittees.
    }
    \item{
    Not all matters are deliberated by the full board. Some are delegated to
subcommittees.
    }
    \item{
    Not all matters are deliberated by the full board. Some are delegated to
subcommittees.
    }
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
}
```

I apologize if the same question has already been asked, because I really don't know how to describe the problem and which keywords to search for. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a compilable MWE (not a piece of code) so that it is easier for us to help you?

Comment: Try with \columnbreak (not sure what the actual name is, the manual might help).

Comment: Add % after subcommittees (i.e subcommittees.%), or move the closing brace to the previous line immediately after the full stop.

Answer (score 1):

I find a workaround to the problem by changing this box into one longer column, so that everything is in one column.

change span = 2 to span = 1 in headerbox definition

```
\headerbox{Contribution}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=1,row=0,above=contact,below=results}{%
```

My solution cannot really solve the problem, so if you think other people may have similar problem, please feel free to answer the question.